# How do you pass parameters in MAUI without using a ViewModel?

Tags: visual-studio-2022, maui

I have this on one page:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(Pages.StartPage), true, new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "LoginData", result }
});
```

`result` is an object/class

In my `Pages.StartPage` I want to get that object. I have tried using `[QueryProperty...` but that always returns a null. E.g.

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(GetLoginData), "LoginData")]
public partial class StartPage : ContentPage

...

private JsonApiResult GetLoginData { set { _loginData = value; }  }
```

I've just started using MAUI, and I am converting an app from Xamarin to MAUI. The pages I have built take care of themselves, so I don't want to use ViewModels, I just need a value from that passed-in object for the page to do its stuff. I don't want to have to rewrite all my pages unless there is no other way

Any help would be much appreciated. I've watched loads of videos on this, and I can't make it work, what am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I should add that to make matters more complex for myself, I am also using Dependency Injection (DI)

Comment: try making `GetLoginData` `public`.  And where/how are you checking the value?  It won't be present in the constructor.

Comment: Does your Xamarin project use AppShell? If not, and you want to retain the same behavior in Maui, then don't use Maui's AppShell. In `App.xaml.cs`, find `MainPage = new AppShell();`. Change it to whatever you have in Xamarin. Bottom line: Whatever you are doing that worked in Xamarin, it should be possible to do similarly in Maui. (Except custom renderers, which have changed substantially.)

Comment: in Xamarin I did this `await Navigation.PushAsync(new Pages.StartPage(result), true);` In MAUI I was hoping to take advantage of dependency injection. I'm obviously doing something wrong as I can get one or other to work but not both lol. @Jason making it public didn't work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private JsonApiResult _loginData;
public JsonApiResult LoginGetData { 
    get  => _loginData; 
    set { _loginData = value; } 
}
```

It seems this was the solution though I can't see why. I'll dig into it another time but right now its working so I can crack on

Answer (score 0):

here it comes an example!

Main page .xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage">

<ScrollView>
    <VerticalStackLayout
        Spacing="25"
        Padding="30,0"
        VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Button
            x:Name="CounterBtn"
            Text="Click me"
            SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
            Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />

    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

On main page .cs:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private async void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Student> myStudentsList = new List<Student>
    {
        new Student {Name="Carlos",Course="IT",Age=18},
        new Student {Name="Juan",Course="IT",Age=19},
        new Student {Name="Leandro",Course="IT",Age=20}
    };

    await Navigation.PushAsync(new PageWithStudentsList(myStudentsList));
    
}
```

PageWithStudentsList .cs :

```
public partial class PageWithStudentsList : ContentPage
{
    public PageWithStudentsList(List<Student> students)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(students);
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And you dont need to use viewmodel!

EDIT: in case you need another example with SHELL NAVIGATION, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#pass-data)  is a microsoft example in their docs! Hope it helps!

Comment: I think DI is my problem. I am getting too adventurous too quickly. This example works but not with DI. This is what I did in Xamarin.

Comment: ShellNavgation seems like you can only do it with ViewModels :(

Answer (score 0):

```
For anyone still looking for the same, another approach using dictionary, which I am just implementing in my app (For keeping C# page neat and clean) is:

 - Create extension method for serializing/deserializing dictionary
   using model/viewmodel.
 - Create a base content page<T> and use [QueryProperty] there at one
   place. 
 - Now. create any page(may use DI) and inherit from our own content
   base page<T>.
 - In XAML specify target type for <T>.
 - Done, Now you can create n number of pages and can control
   data/binding/model/viewmodel from base content page i.e. from a
   centralize place.

 public static Dictionary<string, object> SerializeToDictionay<T>(this T model) where T : class
 {
         return new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Model", model } };
 }

 public static T? DeserializeFromDictionay<T>(this Dictionary<string, object> dictionary) where T : class
 {
     object? objectValue = null;
     dictionary?.TryGetValue("Model", out objectValue);
     return objectValue == null ? null : (T)objectValue;
 }

[QueryProperty(nameof(Model), "Model")]
public class MyBaseContentPage<T> : ContentPage where T : class, new()
{
    public T Model
    {
        set
        {
            this.BindingContext = (value as T);
        }
        get
        {
            return (T)this.BindingContext;
        }
    }

     public MyContentPage()
    {
        Title = typeof(T)?.Name?.Replace("Model", "");
    }

     protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();     
        //Do any other generic binding stuff like setting default props.
     }
}

public partial class MyContentPage: MyBaseContentPage<MyModel>
{
    // Use Model property here for anything. Binding context of this page has already been set by the base page.
}

<MyBaseContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Pages.MyContentPage"
             x:TypeArguments="BMIModel"
             x:Name="bmiDetail">
```